# Erlang SSL - set max send fragment size?

Tags: ssl, erlang

I'm experimenting with [SSL](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html) in Erlang, and I've run into a problem.

The device which I'm talking to requires me to set the max send fragment size. In OpenSSL, this would be done with `SSL_CTX_ctrl(ctx, SSL_CTRL_SET_MAX_SEND_FRAGMENT, ...)`.

Is there any way to do this in Erlang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erlang does not rely on OpenSSL for its SSL implementation.

Unfortunately, it seems that **it currently does not support an option to limit fragment size** or [RFC 6066](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066)'s maximum fragment length negotiation. It simply fragments at 16 KB (2^14), the maximum fragment size defined in [RFC 2246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246).

The code that splits fragments is in [`ssl_record:encode_data/3`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/ssl/src/ssl_record.erl#L340). Supporting an option like OpenSSL seems trivial to implement, and RFC 6066 negotiation does not seem hard either. You would probably just need to extend connection_state record. Please do not hesitate to [submit a patch](https://github.com/erlang/otp/wiki/Submitting-patches).

Comment: Working on it. I'll submit a patch soon.